# Boolean expression solver/simplifier

Tags: java, c++, boolean, eval, solver

I am looking for an Boolean expression solver for very big (but not complex) algebra like:
[Boolsche Ausdrücke vereinfachen (Axiome)](http://www.elektroniker-bu.de/boolesche.htm)
I would like to have some code (c++ or java [or libraries]) to simplify huge boolean expression. I haven´t found something. I just want to do some "simply" convertion like:

```
a && ~a -> 0

a || a && (b || c) -> a
```

But much longer. And I want to use symbolics (a, b, c1, d1..) not TRUE, FALSE, 0 or 1 at the moment.
Thank you in advance.

**Edit:**
If I write it my self, I could use Javaluator and evaluate.
When I have: `(adb+c) && d` I would like to start with multiply out. Anyone an idea?

Comment: no code, but wolfram can [simplify boolean expressions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=CNF+%28P+%26%26+~Q%29+||+%28R+%26%26+S%29+||+%28Q+%26%26+R+%26%26+~S%29). I bet some of the free CAS's like Sage could handle it too.

Comment: Thank you rombo, I know that wolfram can do it. But I need something for my program. If nothing is out there, I must coding it myself. :/

Answer (score 1):

My favorite tool for such tasks is `Logic Friday 1`.
It is free for non-commercial use.

Logic Friday 1 accepts Boolean expressions as formula and as truth table. It includes compiled binaries of Berkeley tools [Espresso](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espresso_heuristic_logic_minimizer) and misII. The latter is being used for multi-level functions.

Another tool is [bc2cnf](http://users.ics.aalto.fi/tjunttil/circuits/). It reads a boolean expression (or a set of expressions) as a "circuit" and translates it to *conjunctive normal form* (CNF), basically a product of OR-expressions. bc2cnf applies some simplification rules during this translation. For expressions of modest size it would be an option to convert the CNF to *disjunctive normal form* (DNF) and use Espresso to get a minimized form.